# Snap lines to points automatically?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I have two vector shapefiles: One file is points representing manholes and the other is a polyline file representing pipes leading to and from the manholes.  I need to snap the lines within a specified distance to the closest manhole.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without doing it manually?

[image: lines -> points]

Update

As per Alexandre, I have exported my shapefiles to spatialite format.  Not sure what to next.

[image]

Update #2
I created a new db file and imported shapefiles into the new db using spatialite-gui,  I adjusted my SQL query but as you can see I get an error "no such column: f.geom"

[image]

Comment: In a Spatialite spatial table(layer), the features geometries are saved in an attribute. The names can be different. In "pipe" table that attribute is called Geometry. I will update my answer assuming that mh also as a Geometry attribute.

Comment: I got a error "no such function: ST_Snap".  I am using QGIS 1.8 on Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: What Spatialite do you have? You can check it in QGIS > Help > About

Comment: _"no such column: f.geom"_ - try with f.Geometry

Comment: My Spatialite version is 3.0.1

Comment: I can't figure out why you have that error. I have created a similar spatialite database and run the SQL code without problems. I'm also using 3.0.1 Spatialite.

Comment: Hı Alexandre, I think İ am at a similar situation lıke GreyHippo. Getting the following message: "no such function: ST_Snap". I am also using QGIS 1.8 on Windows 7 Professional 64bit. Spatialite version is 3.0.1. If you have any further solution, that will be much appreciated. Regards, Imtiaz

Answer (score 26):

If you are willing to put your data in [Postgis](http://postgis.refractions.net/) (or [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/)), you could use [ST_Snap](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Snap.html) to do what you want.

Just use lines layer\table as input, and your points layer as reference, and set the tolerance. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    f.gid as gid,
    ST_Snap(f.Geometry, g.Geometry, 2) as geom
FROM
    pipe as f,
    (SELECT ST_Collect(Geometry) as Geometry
     FROM mh) as g
```

The result is this:

[image]

You can then update your geometries using the feature identifier.

Comment: Where would I put the code "Select...  From..."?  What do mean by "using the feature identifier"?

Comment: After importing your files in the database (postgis or spatialite), you can use DB Manager to see your database tables and run the SQL query (the code) in SQL Window, and then load it in your canvas. Tell me if that works for you, and then we will do the update part.

Comment: Alexandre, see update above.  I exported file to two spatiallite files.

Comment: You should put both files in the same Spatialite Database, just drag say "pipe" to the "mh.sqlite" database. After that update the SQL Code to change "points" to "mh", and "lines" to "pipe". Also adapt "gid" to your "pipe" id. After that you can Execute and load the results.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about QGIS or GRASS, but some quick Googling has yielded [v.clean](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html) in GRASS should do the trick.

Have a look at [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16544/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-snap-loose-points-of-lines-to-close-by-vertices) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27610/snapping-polygons-and-lines).

***Alternatives to QGIS and GRASS:***

If I were to do this in ArcGIS, I would probably store my data in a Feature Dataset in a File Geodatabase and create a [Topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000nn000000) to identify areas where the point layer was not on the endpoints of the lines.  You can then fix the errors using the [Error Inspector](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000z000000).

But, probably the quickest and easiest solution would be in FME.  You could try using the [Snapper Tool](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2013/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#Transformers/snapper.htm) or better yet, the [AnchoredSnapper Tool](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2013/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#Transformers/anchoredsnapper.htm).  If you use the AnchoredSnapper, make sure your snapping type is End Point Snapping.  Of course, you will need a license for FME.  But you can download a 14 day trial if you don't have one.

Comment: I looked at v.clean but it only uses one layer, I need to compare one layer to another. Also, I was more looking for an QGIS/opensource option.

Comment: @GreyHippo, GRASS is opensource

Comment: I know GRASS is opensource but your other options are not.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS Snap Geometries to layer will do what you want. 
See this thread
[How to snap lines to nearest point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132623/how-to-snap-lines-to-nearest-point)

Answer (score -1):

**Manual way**

Qgis -> Settings -> Snapping options (and I'm not sure but it might need CadTools extension) and enable topological editing.

**Automatic way**

v.clean which is in GRASS tools in SEXTANTE toolbox in QGIS.
If you have PostGIS 2.0 then ST_Snap and ST_SnapToGrid() (And there is no reason why you cant use it, it's very good spatial tool)

**Commercial way**

FME and MRF tool (commercial extension, I had an evalution version. It vas very good).

Also I'm intrested about water pipe/sewer management with open source tools, do you have any hints?

Comment: I think that's what GreyHippo means by "doing it manually". Just using the Snapping options, you're going to have to move every dangling node by hand to activate the snapping. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no. i was blind.

Comment: Simplexio, I do NOT want to do it manually.  I was hoping for a plugin or process I don't know about.

Comment: I didn't think you could use GRASS v.clean on two layers?

Comment: if i recall correcly it can fix too short lines. you see, problem you have is not that your manholes arent on right places, its that your sewer network is not topologically correct. And that needs only pipes layer. Every utility network system that i have seen assumes that there is manhole in every sewer intersection.

This offcourse assumes that you want to have correct topology.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing also so how would you incorporate ST_Snap with

                SELECT
            f.gid as gid,
            ST_Snap(f.Geometry, g.Geometry, 2) as geom
        FROM
            pipe as f,
            (SELECT ST_Collect(Geometry) as Geometry
             FROM mh) as g

So far all I get is a selection of the lines that do not intersect but are within 2m of the manhole features.

Comment: select p1.id id , ST_Snap(p1.geom, p2.geom, 2) as geom into newpipes from pipes p1, pipes p2 where p1.id != p2.id . that probably wont work, but if you have manhole centerpoints then i would test something like this : 
select p1.id, ST_Snap(p1.geom,m.geom,2.2 ) FROM pipes p1, manholes m , trying to decrease tested area using " p1.geom && m.geom " (boundingbox test) may or may not help ( it might need st_extend + st_buffer . i havent touched postgis for while