# PostGIS / QGIS Snap Point to Line

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm trying to snap points to lines in PostGIS for use in QGIS, but cannot get it to work.  I have one line in my line table (although it was created by merging multiple lines together) and about 600 points in my point table so would rather not do this manually.

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you already seen this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52232/how-to-snap-lines-to-points-automatically)? Perhaps it may help you as a starting point of view.