# How to snap lines to points automatically in qgis using python

Tags: pyqgis

I have two vector shapefiles: One file is points representing manholes and the other is a polyline file representing pipes leading to and from the manholes. I need to snap the lines within a specified distance to the closest manhole(centroid of point manhole).

How can i do it in qgis using python. I have found the solution in sqlite or postgis but i want to do it in qgis.

```
SELECT
    f.gid as gid,
    ST_Snap(f.Geometry, g.Geometry, 2) as geom
FROM
    pipe as f,
    (SELECT ST_Collect(Geometry) as Geometry
     FROM mh) as g
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to snap lines to points automatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52232/how-to-snap-lines-to-points-automatically)

Comment: @firefly-orange but the solution is in sql script but i need it in qgis.

Comment: It also directs you to the v.clean tool

Comment: You can use SQL on your non database layer with the DB Manager by using the "Virtual layers" category :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using processing toolbox function "Snap geometries to layer" or try using spatial index